# Drush 12 PHP Fatal Error Uncaught Error: Class "Drush\Config\Environment" not found in .../vendor/drush/drush/drush.php:129

Tags: drupal, drupal-10

For xampp drupal 10 site using composer I updated drush/drush to 12.  However, now when I run the drush command I am receiving PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Drush\Config\Environment" not found in .../vendor/drush/drush/drush.php:129.  I am also not seeing the /bin folder within the vendor folder.  Composer update and install run smoothly with seemingly no errors.

I have tried a number of things including removing the vendor and compoesr.lock files and running composer install and composer update, upgrading and downgrading drush versions to 11.6 and 12.x versions, and adding an environment variable for the $PATH.